# While fetching more than 1000 records its shows error, if its less than 1000 records then its displays without any issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

While fetching more than 1000 records its shows error, if its less than 1000    records then its displays without any issue
    The error is shown below

```
System Error: Comparison method violates its general contract! 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

The application is in spring-hibernate framework

the line in which the error shows

```
Collections.sort(adHoc, new SortList());
Collections.sort(hourly, new SortList());
Collections.sort(daily, new SortList());
Collections.sort(weekly, new SortList());
Collections.sort(monthly, new SortList());
Collections.sort(quarterly, new SortList());
Collections.sort(yearly, new SortList());*
```

**Update: Added Code for `SortList`**

```
class SortList implements Comparator<MeasurementReading> {
    public int compare(MeasurementReading o1, MeasurementReading o2) {
        String cat1 = o1.getType().getQuantity().getCategory().getName();
        String quantityName1 = o1.getType().getQuantity().getName();
        String name1 = cat1 + "- " + quantityName1;

        String cat2 = o2.getType().getQuantity().getCategory().getName();
        String quantityName2 = o2.getType().getQuantity().getName();
        String name2 = cat2 + "-" + quantityName2;

        return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code for `SortList`

Comment: As @geoand says, please paste the code for SortList. Additionally, have you searched for this? I think this is a fairly common problem!

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is in your `Comparator` implementation.  For some reason it does not obey one of the invariants that a `Comparator` is supposed to obey.

The fact that this only shows up with collections larger than 1000 is coincidental.  The larger the collection is, the more likely it is that the sort will encounter a group of elements that trigger the incorrect behaviour.

The contract (from the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-)) is as follows:

> *The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`. (This implies that `compare(x, y)` must throw an exception if and only if `compare(y, x)` throws an exception.)*
>
> *The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0))` implies `compare(x, z)>0`.*
>
> *Finally, the implementor must ensure that `compare(x, y)==0` implies that `sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z))` for all `z`.*

---

We can't be more specific without seeing the code of your `Comparator`.

---

**UPDATE**

On the face of it, your comparator looks OK.  However, you are relying on a various methods to give you the information you assemble into strings to compare.  If the result of one of those method calls changes while you are sorting, then you are liable to violate the contract.  I suspect that your measurements are changing while you are sorting.